# Prove $f$ is integrable and then integrate on $[0,1]^3$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $Q = [0, 1]^3$ and let $f : Q \to \mathbb R$ be given by
$$ f(x, y, z) = \begin{cases}
1, & \text{if } x < y < z; \\
0, & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$
Prove $f$ is integrable, then integrate.

Comment: Riemann integral. I dumbed down the question by starting with f: [0,1] x [0,1] --> R with f=1 if x<y, f=0 otherwise. But I don't know how to do the original question. Can i just throw in an extra [0,1] and x<y<z  with brute force? How should I even start?

Comment: What do you know about Riemann integrals? Do you know normal domains or Fubini type theorems?

Comment: this is a question from a problem set for the Fubini's theorem.

Comment: That makes it pretty easy. Where do you get stuck?

Comment: ok, i get how to prove it is integrable now; but i don't know how to integrate this.  i mean the function only takes on value 0 or 1, am i missing some important concepts here

Comment: Please post what you have tried. Otherwise it is likely that your post get closed by lack of details.